# How to connect a datatable in multiple datatable?

Tags: c#, database, gridview, visual-studio-2013

Got problem connection,there're more than 1 datatable in single Database.When I try

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\...\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

It's empty gridview, dunno how to select datatable a choose one to connect it and show on datagridview

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from table1 where name like('" + textBox1.Text + "\')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            con.Close();
        }
```

for searching data in datatable..

Comment: I don't see any `DataTable` in your code, I just see an `SqlConnection`.

Comment: Just wanna know how to show a table select one.

Comment: And you are seriously going to have massive performance problems everytime you press a key on your keyboard. Your SQL Syntax is also incorrect as you are using a LIKE statement but not specifying the wildcard type parameters around your input i.e SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE %textbox1.Text%. You also should consider parameterizing your query for security reasons too. You also are executing the query then also filling it using the data adapter. Most likely the input you type does not work/records not found as you are doing this on every keystroke and there is no data coming back

Answer (score 1):

you not add DataBind() method in your code

you just add

```
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView1.DataBind();
```